# Howto compile a kernel module on CentOS [required packages]

Tags: iptables, compile, gcc, kernel-module

What `yum` commands do I need to get available packages installed on CentOS to build a **iptables** MATCH ***kernel module***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yum install kernel-devel
>
> yum install iptables-devel
>
> yum install gcc
>
> yum install make

Is all I needed

Answer (score 2):

If you need all the standard build tools, start with:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Then hop over to here:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

Comment: This is good for a full fledged development environment. But on a server, my answer pulls in less packages.